# Ubuntu 18.04 USB mouse stop working suddenly

Tags: 18.04, usb, mouse

In Ubuntu 18.04 , my USB mouse starts working suddenly . Mouse pointer does not move at all . When I type xinput ,I see that USB mouse is not shown .

```
xinput 
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Sony Vaio Jogdial                         id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera: USB 2.0 Camera            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

when USB mouse is working it used it show as

```
Virtual core pointer                        id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Sony Vaio Jogdial                         id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ PixArt USB Optical Mouse                  id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS GlidePoint                  id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sony Vaio Keys                            id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB 2.0 Camera: USB 2.0 Camera            id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

In second listing id=13 ,is my usb mouse . After reading a bit on the various forums , i tried disabling id=12  (touchpad ) assuming that is interfering in usb mouse behavior.

command was - xinput disable 13 .

But that does not seem to be correct . as mouse still freezes . I am resorted to trial and errors .

1. reboot my machine
2. swapping my USB mouse from one port to another
   3.trying with xinput disable 13 // disable touchpad

any solutions. This USB mouse works fine on Windows 10 and Windows 7 .
I also tried using a different mouse . still issue persists.

Comment: I would recommend checking out https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingMouseDetection. It has multiple solutions for the problem you are having. Thanks,
Mark

Comment: thanks @Mark . in dmesg , i see following error for usb mouse ,  usb2-1.5: USB disconnect , device number 76  , new low speed usb device number 77 using ehci-pci , usb 2.1.5 : device descriptor read/all , error -32 .

Comment: `dmesg -Hw` used to tail log and catch error messages when mouse stops working. Then google the error message. Solution will depend on error messages. In my case nouveau video driver was outputting an error just before mouse & keyboard stopped working. Switching to use NVIDIA driver (Ubuntu - Software & Updates - Additional Drivers) solved issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've just found a working solution.
In your case, the correct answer will be:

```
xinput reattach 13 4
```

For me it just restored the mouse pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Went to ubuntu recovery menu and booted ubuntu in recovery mode. mouse has started working.